# parentNode becomes null after removing previous child element

Tags: javascript

So, I'm trying to have a button add another dropdown (DD in my code) to the page, and it works just dandy, except when I try to remove (which "works") the remaining node no longer has the parentNode set properly.

Here is my code:

```js
function insertAfter(newNode, elem) {
    elem.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, elem.nextSibling);
}


function addSwitchMenu() {
    var lastDD = dropdowns.switches.last();
    var newDD = lastDD.cloneNode();
    newDD.innerHTML = lastDD.innerHTML;
    var oldButton = document.getElementById("add-switch");
    var newButton = oldButton.cloneNode();
    var newBR = document.createElement("br");
    oldButton.value = '-';
    oldButton.id = 'remove-switch';
    oldButton.onclick = function() {
        var index = dropdowns.switches.indexOf(newDD);
        dropdowns.switches.splice(index,1);
        lastDD.parentNode.removeChild(lastDD);
        oldButton.parentNode.removeChild(oldButton);
        newBR.parentNode.removeChild(newBR);
        updateResults();
    }
    dropdowns.switches.push(newDD);
    console.log(newDD);
    console.log(lastDD.parentNode);
    insertAfter(newDD, lastDD);
    insertAfter(newButton, lastDD);
    insertAfter(newBR, lastDD);
}
```

And basically I call this function, then I call the remove function of the first one, then I call this function once more using the node that was created with the first one. I'm guessing it's something to do with the referencing node being removed, but the new node has a parentNode up until the other node is removed. Why? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you give us a working example so we can do some debugging and exploring of our own? Also, once you remove an element, it's `parentNode` will be `null`. It's no longer in a document, it's just a stand-alone element.

Comment: @NobleMushtak I'm talking about a node that is still on the page. Could it be due to the cloning of the node?

Comment: @NobleMushtak I've ruled out that it's the cloning. Let me try and get a JS fiddle going.

Comment: Test out `var span, span2; document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {span = document.getElementById("hello"); span2 = span.cloneNode(); span.parentNode.appendChild(span2); span.parentNode.removeChild(span); console.log(span2.parentNode); });` with `<span id = "hello"></span>` in the body to begin with. That should log a `<body>` element.

Comment: Why are you using `newDD.innerHTML = lastDD.innerHTML` to populate the content of the `newDD` instead of just cloning the entire structure?

Comment: @cookiemonster because I have no idea what I'm doing :)

Comment: `.cloneNode(true)` will clone the descendants too. I'm having trouble understanding the issue from your description. However, It seems like you're giving the old button a new ID, but never giving one to the new button. So on the next click, there'll be no `"add-switch"` to fetch. Is that the issue?

Comment: @Cookiemonster No, it's strictly an issue with the parentNode not being set after removing this initial element. So basically, I have my first element, node1 and I call the add function. This takes node1, clones it, and makes node2, and this is all fine and dandy. I can then either do another add or remove node1. If I remove node1, node2 NO LONGER HAS A parentNode, but it did just before this. That's where my issue is. Also, I've edited the OP to show my insertAfter function

Comment: Is it this line: `var index = dropdowns.switches.indexOf(newDD);`? Seems like you should be getting the index of the `lastDD`.

Comment: I am also having the same issue

Comment: @Ramsey If you open another question, feel free to post a link here or tag me. I'm a lot better at JavaScript than i was 8 years ago, and I'd love to help haha

Comment: lol, I forgot to delete my comment after I solved my problem. The problem was that I was trying to get the reference of the parent but I found out this wasn't possible with the way I use in javascript